# Opening an external MSG file in Outlook with full functionality

Tags: c#, email, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

I thought I was clever when deciding to use MSG files for an e-mail template functionality in our Windows Application.

The idea was to give the users the ability to save MSG files in the system that contains merge codes that will result in ready e-mails being generated with data automatically merged in from our database and the formatting all done etc.

That all worked well. I load the MSG on the server, do a lot of merging operations and transfer it to the client where it is opened via simple process.start().

It opens perfectly as an Outlook e-mail ready to send.

Or so I thought

Until our customers began complaining that their Secure Email sending addon in Outlook no longer was working for these e-mails, and we have observed several other functions not working such as O365 encryption.

I believe this is down to the fact that opening an MSG in editable mode gives you a sendable mail in Outlook context, but it seems to be somehow detached from the Outlook application that it needs for the addons to work...

Then what do I do? I really would like to have the MSG, but all I try seems not to work.

I have tried to go back to Office.Interop using what is recommended:

```
app.Session.OpenSharedItem(path-to-msg)
```

This opens it fine, but is still seems detached since the addons do not work.

Yes I could make a new mail item in the Outlook application or use MAPI, but that will force me to construct the mail once over, and if I need to decompose the MSG , the idea of having them is lost.

Does anyone know of a solution to this, or some clever alternative to what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using.oft instead of.msg .

The result of this is,that the message is opened in another context in Outlook.